# Jquery post method not working

Tags: php, jquery, post

i am using jquery to check whether the name entered by the user already exists in the database as shown.
My form:

```
<tr>
    <td>Username:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="us" size="38" id="name"></br>
        <span id="usmsg" class="msg">Username already exists!</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Jquery Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#usmsg').hide();
    $('#addc').click(function(event){

        var us=$('#name').val();
        alert(us);     //just to check this code is executed or not.

        $.post('checkname.php', {'myuser' : us}, function(data) {
            if(data=='exist') {
                alert('success');
            }
            else {
                alert('failure');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The file checkname.php where the value of username goes:

```
<?php include("includes/connection.php");?>
<?php
    $myuser = $_POST['myuser'];
    $qry = "select username from users where username='$myuser'";
    $res = $con->query($qry);
    $r = $res->num_rows;
    if($r>0)
        echo 'exist';
    else
        echo 'notexist';
?>
```

The problem is that it alerts me the username properly according to the code

```
alert(us);
```

but then it does not echo the success or failure message and the page simply loads with the value in the textbox reset.i have also checked the php file and its working fine.Any help?

Comment: That php code looks like it is vulnerable to SQL injections. You should be using a database wrapper that uses prepared statements, it does not look like you are doing this as you have put the parameter in the query itself

Comment: yes i am not using it.Can u direct me to a tutorial for the same?

Comment: What't the element with ID addc? Anchor tag or Button?

Comment: Videos 8 - 11 http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLfdtiltiRHWF5Rhuk7k4UAU1_yLAZzhWc

Comment: @Dikesh its a button.

Comment: Can you show more HTML code? Because I am sure your form is getting submitted on button click.

Comment: @Dikesh <input type="Submit" name="add" value="Add Customer" id="addc">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is First change the button type from **submit** to **button** so that on click your form don't get submitted on button click.

Then based on Ajax reponse you can submit your form like below:

```
$('#addc').click(function() {
    //prevent the default action of the click like form submit

    var us = $('#name').val();
    alert(us); //just to check this code is executed or not.

    $.post('checkname.php', {
    'myuser': us
    }, function(data) {
    if ($.trim(data) === 'exist') {
        alert('success');
        // This line will submit the form.
        $('form').submit();
    } else {
        alert('failure');
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: On following this and changing data=='exist' to data==='exist',it is not showing any of the success or failure messages.Actually now the problem is in handling the 'data' that comes from the php file.
inspite of its value being 'exist',it executes the else part.

Comment: can you print `data` in console before checking it in `if else` condition?

Comment: yes,the value of data comes correct on alerting it using alert(data); but inspite of its value being exist,else part gets executed.

Comment: try changing data==='exist' to data=='exist'

Comment: i was talking about the error with data=='exist' only,with data==='exist',neither of the conditions are getting executed.

Comment: What is the error? And what is the output when you do `alert(data)`?

Comment: output is exist.Now as per the if condition,it should alert 'success' but its alerting 'failure'.

Comment: Ok so this is the problem even with `==` . What is the `typeof data` ?

Comment: its a string with value 'exist'. see the checkname.php file in the code.

Comment: This is strange my friend. It should alert with success then. But atleast now your page is not loaded with value reset, right?

Comment: yes that is solved with event.preventDefault() but the comparison operator is not working properly.

Comment: Hm.. I have no clue now.

Comment: Hey can you use trim() method on data and then compare? See I have updated my code.

Comment: Its working man but on using input type='button' instead of input type='submit' and using event.preventDefault() at the start of the script,how to undo the effect of this function at the end?i used
    $('formid').unbind('submit');
But its not working.

Comment: remove `event.preventDefault()`. It is not required since you are using input `type='button'`. Just use the entire code which I have written. Because it does form submit when validation is true.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the problem is your click action is triggering a page reload, like a form submit or anchor click. So prevent the default action of the click event inside your handler.

Since your click action is triggering a page load, it does not wait for the ajax callback to get executed because of that the alert() is not appearing.

```
$('#addc').click(function (event) {
    //prevent the default action of the click like form submit
    event.preventDefault();

    var us = $('#name').val();
    alert(us); //just to check this code is executed or not.

    $.post('checkname.php', {
        'myuser': us
    }, function (data) {
        if (data == 'exist') {
            alert('success');
        } else {
            alert('failure');
        }
    });
});
```